# How does ordering by inside window function work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE employee 
(
     name varchar(10),
     gender varchar(30), 
     salary int
);

INSERT INTO employee 
VALUES ('Mark', 'male', '5000'),
       ('John', 'male', '4500'),
       ('Pam', 'female', '5500'),
       ('Sara', 'female', '4000'),
       ('Todd', 'male', '3500'),
       ('Mary', 'female', '5000'),
       ('Ben', 'male', '6500'),
       ('Jodi', 'female', '7000'),
       ('Tom', 'male', '5500'),
       ('Ron', 'male', '5000');

SELECT 
    name, gender, salary, 
    AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY gender ORDER BY salary 
                      rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS ave_sal
FROM
    employee
```

My question is, in the output, the salary table is not ordered by when I use the 'rows' parameter. If I remove the 'rows' parameter it is properly ordered by. Can someone please tell me How does ordering by inside window function work?

Comment: Side note: if you insert data into an `INT` column - you should ***NOT*** put that data in the `INSERT INTO` statement into single quotes (thus making it a string literal, which needs to be converted to an `INT` internally)! Just use `.... VALUES ('Ron', 'male', 5000);`

Comment: @marc_s Got your point, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "order" in a SQL table (or in a result set) unless you explicitly use an `ORDER BY` clause.  Also, the `ROWS` clause of your call to `AVG()` is excessive, because `AVG()` without an `ORDER BY` clause will default to the entire partition without bounds.  So, you may just use:

```sql
SELECT name, gender, salary, AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY gender) AS ave_sal
FROM employee
ORDER BY AVG(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY gender);
```

Note that window functions can be used in the `ORDER BY` clause, in addition to the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Bet you didn't know: since `ORDER BY` is evaluated after `SELECT`, you can write `ORDER BY ave_sal` or `ORDER BY 4`

Comment: @Charlieface No, I don't know that to be true on SQL Server ... is it true?

Comment: Quote from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "The column names referenced in the ORDER BY clause must correspond to either a column or column alias in the select list or to a column defined in a table specified in the FROM clause without any ambiguities. If the ORDER BY clause references a column alias from the select list, the column alias must be used standalone, and not as a part of some expression in ORDER BY clause, for example:"

Comment: Point taken.  I find it hard to keep track of the order by nuances from all the different RDBMS.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` clause in a window frame does not allow placeholders (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bf703/2).  Don't confuse that `ORDER BY` with the `ORDER BY` for the entire query.